# Should the pre-defined MVC ApplicationDbContext be moved to a different layer, domain or storage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, domain-driven-design

When using MVC5 I add a domain layer and storage layer using dependency injection for all the business data.  But I have always left the ApplicationDbContext in the main MVC application layer project.

I've read a great many posts on SO and see many people recommend moving the ApplicationDbContext out of the MVC project.  I'd like to understand why ApplicationDbContext should or should not be moved.  Are there any reasons to not move this context?

On the one hand, ApplicationDbContext uses a data model which suggests it should be moved to the storage layer but that will require large DTO's.  On the other hand, ApplicationDbContext really relates primarily to application access and I have a separate roles/permissions functionality for the business data anyway.  Several SO posts also suggested checking roles in the application layer, not the domain layer, but that seems suspect; don't we want to check business roles in the domain layer?

So I'm confused and before I go to the work to move the ApplicationDbContext to a different layer, I'd like to make sure I'm making a sound and informed decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a must, but it is advisable if you are doing DDD and your project tends to grow large.

Although DDD is not about implementation details, DDD asks for a clear separation of concerns. Then you should separate domain logic from infrastructure.

You could achieve that separation in many ways. One way would be to have a single project with folders for Domain, Application and Infrastructure, and have your DbContext reside in the Infrastructure folder. This is suitable for small projects.

In large projects, however, I would recommend you to evaluate the **Clean Architecture**, which will take this separation to project level.

---

> I'd like to understand why ApplicationDbContext should or should not be moved. Are there any reasons to not move this context?

It can be moved, there's no rule against it. But the tooling will then require you to specify both startup and database projects as parameters, like this:

```
dotnet ef database update --project <path> --startup-project <path>
```

But since you're using MVC5, you're probably not using EF Core. In case of EF 6 or lower, you'll be using the Package Manager Console (PMC) to manage migrations and database-updates, which will make your life easier in that regard, since you can mark you MVC project as the Startup Project from the context menu, and select the target project from a dropdown control in the PMC.

---

> Several SO posts also suggested checking roles in the application layer, not the domain layer, but that seems suspect; don't we want to check business roles in the domain layer?

Yes, roles are related to permissions, which are business rules. People probably recommend checking that in the application layer because you need to pull this data from the database, but you could do it like this:

Use the **Specification Pattern** to represent roles and permissions as an specification in the Domain Layer. But the IRepository interfaces would best be defined in Application Layer, as they represent infrastructure (which will be concretely implemented in the Infrastructure Layer). So you would start the role-checking in the Application Layer by using repositories to retrieve data, but the actual permission validation would be done by an Specification in the Domain Layer.

That would be one way to do it.

Comment: See more about the Specification Pattern at https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/

Comment: See more about the Clean Architecture at https://paulovich.net/clean-architecture-for-net-applications/